# How do I detect in jQuery if the contents of an anchor tag contains a string?

Tags: jquery

How can i check `<a href="#">sometext</a>` equals something, trying to reach something like this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    if ($("a:contains('sometext')")) {
        alert('sometext');
    }
    else {
        alert('text');  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

almost.... Either:

```
$('a:contains("something")').click(function(){
  // pass
});
```

To only bind to elements with the specified text, or:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  if ($(this).text().indexOf('something') !== -1){
    // pass
  }
});
```

to check at the time of clicking.

Comment: Does this even exist `$(this).contains('something')`? I think you're mixin things. There's the `:contains` selector and `$.contains()` which only works with DOM elements.

Comment: @elclanrs: Touche. Yes, going between c# and mvc over here for a project and helping on here. Fixed, good catch.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (/some regex/.test($(this).text()))
```

Comment: I have to ask...why go straight to regex and not just [`String.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) (which I also believe is more widely supported)?

Comment: @BradChristie: Regexes add more flexibility.  Also, regex is universally supported (although I believe `String.indexOf` also is)

Comment: I thought I remember running in to trouble with `.test()` at some point, but you may be right. However, for what's being checked regex add too much overhead, IMHO.